# How to implement Let's Encrypt for CentOS / Apache

Tags: apache-http-server, centos, https

I am running CentOS 7 and apache 2.4 and would like to implement [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/). What is the process for this?

Comment: I understand this is in late beta at current and the instructions may change over time.

Comment: Have you followed the instructions on the website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](https://letsencrypt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/using.html#apache) of Let's Encrypt, you have to run:

```
./letsencrypt-auto --apache
```

Then select the domains you want to secure*. Let's encrypt will generate everything you need. Then you have to link the files in the apache SSL configuration under `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf` or wherever you have the configuration for your ssl certificates.

Something like this

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem
```

*When I tested it, not all domains where shown. You might need to use the manual mode (also explained in the docs)

Comment: Since I didn't find much on this in the internet I wrote a [blog post](https://pius-ladenburger.de/blog/2015/12/14/using-lets-encrypt-with-apache2/) on it which goes through the installation step by step – maybe it helps.